# Best place to write permission code in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Where is the best place to check some condition before doing an database updation in Laravel.

During form submission, I am using `form validation class` for handling those request validation.

I have tables `users`, `awards`, `award_user`

Here when I am assigning user to an award, in some cases, one award can be assigned by maximum one user, I have to check whether already user assigned or not in when trying to assign user to award,

I written code in my controller and throwing 403 exception as follows

```
    //get award
    $award = Award::with('type')->findOrFail($id);
    //get award assigned members by department
    $userCount = AwardUser::join('users', 'users.id', 'award_user.user_id')
            ->where('award_id', $id)
            ->where('users.department_id', $departmentId)
            ->count();
    //not allowed to assign more than one if max person > 0
    if ($award->type->max_person > 0 && $userCount > 0) {
        abort(403, 'No more user allowed to assign!');
    }
    $award->members()->attach($userId, ['created_by' => Auth::user()->id]);
}
```

Is it good method or should I follow any other methods.

Comment: A custom validator might be most appropriate. There's also the form request's `authorize` function.

Comment: inside form validator class, is it good to write database operation.?

Comment: No reason you can't. The built-in Laravel `exists` validator does a database query, for example.

Comment: @ceejayoz when listing awards, I have to pass parameter in URL and filter awards according to that. now I am doing these filtering in the controller itself. Is it good? it would be appreciated for your advice.